# Can you create a new Apple ID just to store WhatsApp, Telegram, and other information that was associated with your old phone number/old Apple ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

I would like to start a new chapter in my life and I intend to get a new phone number.

I am currently using iphone X and I would like to retain my apple ID as it has all the purchases that I have made in the past.

However, I do not want to lose my conversations, data that is found in applications (for example, whatsapp, telegram) and I was hoping that I could transfer into a secondary phone (my old iphone 6 Plus - running on iOS 12.5 and create a new apple ID so that it will not conflict with my current apple ID and new phone number.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Is the iPhone X running an older or equal version of iOS 12.5 ?

Comment: Also, not sure I understand it all: you want to get a new phone number _and_ create a new AppleID?

Comment: Hi there, sorry if my phrasing is unclear. I want to get a new phone number and link with my old apple ID. I want to create a new apple ID so that the whatsapp messages that i found in the old phone number can be stored in there.